# Multiple tasks using Parallel Foreach and WhenAny. Is that possible?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, c#-5.0

I want to scrape several websites at the same time, but just add the information to the database one by one. Meanwhile my code looks similar to this:

```
        List<SiteMetadata> sitesList = GetSites();
        var tasks = new List<Task<SiteMetadata>>();

        foreach (var item in sitesList)
            tasks.Add(item.LoadMetaDataAsync());

        int totalSites = sitesList.Count;
        int finishedSites = 0;

        int errors = 0;
        while (totalSites != finishedSites)
        {
            var tempSite = await Task.WhenAny(tasks.ToArray());
            //WRITE HERE TO DB!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            tasks.Remove(tempSite);

            var tempLog = apiHandler.WriteToDatabase(tempSite.Result);

            if (tempLog.Type == LogType.Error)
            {
                errors++;
                LogsHandler.AddToLog(tempLog);
            }

            finishedSites++;
        }
```

I want is to increase the efficiency here and replace the:

```
    var tasks = new List<Task<SiteMetadata>>();
    foreach (var item in sitesList)
        tasks.Add(item.LoadMetaDataAsync());
```

to something like this:

```
    var runAll = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(sitesList, item => item.LoadMetaDataAsync()));
```

But the problem is that I dont know how to get the first task that finishes and to the database one by one. There is anyway to do this using the Parallel or something similar or even something more efficient than what I am doing right now?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could try to implement a event that is triggered on the end of `LoadMetaDataAsync`. This event will inform you when a task is finished. then you only have to fill your database int the event handling function with your data

Comment: Throwing more threads at an asynchronous operation won't help. You're not bound by the numbers of cores you have, you're bound by the network anyway. Async methods (when written correctly) yield control immediately.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that would suggest that your proposal would _"increase the efficiency"_, or even perform as well as what you've got now. If you think it would, provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the efficiency problem you have now, explain what that problem is, and why you believe there is something that can be done to improve it.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to scrape several websites at the same time, but just add the information to the database one by one.

Your code already does that.

> I want is to increase the efficiency here and replace

That won't increase efficiency; it will decrease it. `Parallel.ForEach` is a parallel operation, where "parallel" means "concurrent using multiple threads". Starting multiple tasks and then combining them with `Task.WhenAll` is how you do concurrency *without* using multiple threads. **Not** using unnecessary threads is more efficient.

However, it looks like what you're doing may benefit from TPL Dataflow, which allows you to define a "pipeline" to send data through. It won't increase your "efficiency", but it may clarify the code.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Why using just one thread is more efficient than several ones?

Comment: Every thread is a kernel object and has a pretty good amount of memory reserved for its stack.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're facing the "multi providers - one consumer" issue. I suggest you to use [Thread-Safe Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).

In the following console sample, I use `ConcurrentBag` to store task results, then in main thread, I use a while loop to grab a result and print it out(You can do this in your own work thread). Note there isn't any lock in the entire program:

```
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    private static readonly ConcurrentBag<int> Bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await SampleTask());
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
            int item;
            if (Bag.TryTake(out item))
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    private static async Task SampleTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(Random.Next(1000));
        Bag.Add(Random.Next(10));
    }
```

Comment: Ok. I think thats already better, but there is anyway to use the Parallel.Foreach here?

Comment: @juanora If your loop body is "async", there's no need to  use `Parallel.Foreach`